# When I use onPress, I would like to set both these states at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-state-management

What I have noticed is that either one of these onPress functions works when used alone. But I want them both to happen together. How could I do it?

```
onPress={()=>setGroupSelected(item.groupName) setModalVisible(false)}
```

I want to use setGroupSelected and setModalVisible at the same time. The entire block of code that uses the above line is as follows

```
<FlatList    data={groups} 
             keyExtractor={item=>item.groupID.toString()}        
             renderItem={({item})=> <SelectionBoxComponent inputText={item.groupName} 
             onPress={()=>setGroupSelected(item.groupName) setModalVisible(false)}  > 
             </SelectionBoxComponent> }
                    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line arrow functions return the value indicated without a return statement.

Try changing this (check the onPress function change)

```
<FlatList    data={groups} 
             keyExtractor={item=>item.groupID.toString()}        
             renderItem={({item})=> <SelectionBoxComponent inputText={item.groupName} 
             onPress={()=>setGroupSelected(item.groupName) setModalVisible(false)}  > 
             </SelectionBoxComponent> }
                    />
```

to this

```
<FlatList    data={groups} 
             keyExtractor={item=>item.groupID.toString()}        
             renderItem={({item})=> <SelectionBoxComponent inputText={item.groupName} 
             onPress={()=> {
              setGroupSelected(item.groupName);
              setModalVisible(false);
             }}> 
             </SelectionBoxComponent> }
                    />
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusing way of explaining the return. To simplify take this example:

Comment: (item) => item.groupName

Comment: would return the item.groupName (notice no return statement)

Comment: Thank you soo much for the help. Your code fixed my problem instantly.